# How can I share a single page of the pdf or other documents in iOS?

Tags: ios, pdf, sharing

From time to time I need to share a single page from a pdf on iPhone or iPad into some chat in a fast way.
The shared page is supposed to be printed, so it should be of good quality.

I open pdf's from the "Files" app in a standard viewer.
The fastest way I know is to take a screenshot and remove black borders, but the resulted image has pretty poor quality.

There are many tools which can split pdf into parts, but it is way too long operation when you need to share a page on a call.

I believe there should be some fast way of one-page sharing similar to printing only the range of pages.

Answer (score 5):

The trick with "Print" on iOS

1. On opened document click **Share** -> **Print**
2. In **Printer Options** select **Range** and choose pages you need to share
3. Now you need to scroll pages carousel to the chosen pages (this part is most annoying when you have 10+ pages, and the hell for 100+)
4. **Pinch out** one of the chosen pages (you can't pinch unchosen pages, this is why you should scroll to the first chosen one)
5. You will see another preview screen with only chosen pages with the **Share** button
6. Now you can share these pages wherever you want

pros: shares one or multiple pages in original quality
cons: pretty tricky for big documents

Comment: It took me a while to figure out the “pinch out” part. But I stuck with it. And it worked! Very handy (for shorter documents)

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the PDF in Preview, open the left sidebar to show the miniatures.
2. Now select in the miniatures all the pages you don't need and delete them (Command - backspace). Use the Shift key to select a range of pages.
3. Select the File menu while holding the option key and select 'Save as'. Now the saved file is a PDF with just the remaining page.
4. Be sure not to overwrite the original file!

Of course, you can always open the Print dialog, select only the desired page and then select 'Save as PDF'.

Comment: I clarified the question with ios :) I thought the ios tag would be enough

Comment: but mac os tricks would also be helpful

Comment: there is a simpler way for mac os - mark pages you need in the sidebar, Cmnd+P, tick "selected pages" and in the PDF dropdown in the left-bottom choose "Open in preview", then you can save it wherever you want